# LinkedList references

Tags: c#, linked-list, reference, element

I am trying to insert an element into a linked list in c#. I get an invaliderOperationException because I think I do not have a reference to the actually linked-list-node.

```
private static LinkedList<ScoreNode> scores;
private static LinkedListNode<ScoreNode> posNode;
```

Current I set posNode to the element in scores that satisfies a certain condition
then I use the AddBefore method to add a new LinkedListNode(ScoreNode) before posNode.
So if I am correct, I think that I get the exception because there is nothing stored before posNode in memory. So how could i get a reference from an element in scores?

Comment: Might be worth showing the code you are using to add the new node...

Comment: You need to show the code where you set `posNode` to an element of `scores`, and also the code that shows your insertion. We wouldn't be able to help you without these two pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize it?

```
private static LinkedList<ScoreNode> scores = new LinkedList<ScoreNode>();
```

Comment: Of course he did - otherwise, he'd be getting a null reference exception.

Comment: If they hadn't, it would be a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: 0 = +1 for effort, -1 for clearly unrelated answer (one would get NullReferenceException exception)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm sorry. From the code I saw I didn't see it initialized. I cant assume anything.